# How to generate one file minimized of printjs or another javascript library

Tags: javascript, printjs

I need to download a generated file (minimized or similar) of this library:
https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/tree/e42c350267e7c869387e8084b90119f86c7d70e2

How i can do it ?
Thanks

Comment: It says to install it via npm or yarn. Google either of those and install one of them. Note [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using `npm` when adding dependencies to your project.

However, if the library uploads compiled and minified files with its GitHub releases:
https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/releases

Download the files under the `assets` section for the version you want.

For example, for version 1.5 (currently its latest version), the download link for the lib minified js is this:
https://github.com/crabbly/Print.js/releases/download/v1.5.0/print.min.js